# Change SQL Query In Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have an embedded SQL Query in my Excel 2007 workbook, this was created by going to Data then Connections and inserting the query that way.  Now I need to alter the queries where clause.  How can I manipulate the embedded SQL Where clause on each worksheet (close to 100) in the workbook?

I need to do such using C# and the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do this.

First method is to go to the 'Data' tab in excel and click 'Connections'.  This brings up a form called 'Workbook Connections' where each of your queries will be listed.  Select the first query and click 'Properties' which will bring up another form called 'Connection Properties'.  Select the 'Definition' tab and in the 'Command Text' box you will find your entire SQL command where you can edit the WHERE clause.  Then click 'OK' and move on to the next query.

The alternative method is to place your cursor in the table of the first query.  This will cause a new tab on the ribbon called 'TABLE TOOLS' to appear.  In the 'External Table Data' section of the ribbon is a 'Properties' button (also found in the  'Data' tab in the 'Connections' section, or when you right click inside the table).  When you select this, a form called 'External Data Properties' will show.  Next to the name of your query is a little square button, click it.  This brings up the same 'Connection Properties' form as in the previous method.  From here, select the 'Definition' tab and in the 'Command Text' box you will find your entire SQL command where you can edit the WHERE clause.  Then click 'OK' and 'OK again and move on to the next query.

Comment: This is the manual course of action.  How could this be completed using C#?